# Changable favicon

Tags: php, multisite, html, cms, favicon

I am looking for help to put single page favicon that would overwrite global one.
Say for example I have wordpress website that is example.com and it has favicon set for every page. What I want is for example.com/page3 to have diffrent favicon.
I have seen quite a few options around but I cannot figure out how to make it work (my coding skills are limited). This solution:

```
<?php
    echo '<link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://www.yoursite.com/favicon.ico?t=' . time() . '" />';
?>
```

Is marked as working one, but I cannot figure out how to set it up.
Thank you for help

Comment: You can add a new header for page3 and have different favicon rel link for that.

Comment: Thank you for answer but how can I do that? 
Page have header built with Elementor page builder.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a modern theme, where you can upload a favicon with the theme customizer (rather than a hardcoded url in the `header.php`), you can simply use a filter. Take a look at the function [`get_site_icon`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_site_icon_url/). As you can see it returns the url of the image that you have uploaded using the customizer. However, before it does so, it runs it through a filter, allowing you to change it under any condition you would like. For instance, to change it when you are on a page with ID=3:

```
add_filter( 'get_site_icon_url','wpse318165_filter_favicon', 10, 3 );
function wpse318165_filter_favicon ($url, $size, $blog_id) {
  global $post;
  if ( is_page( 3 ) ) $url = 'path-to-other-favicon';
  return $url;
  }
```

Answer (score -2):

Here is the link: https://elementor.com/blog/header-footer-builder/

there is a video link on this page which explains how can you create/use multiple header with Elementor plugin.

Normally if you have FTP access go to theme folder and duplicate **header.php** and name it something relevant **ie. header-blog.php**

Then you can call that file in your page/templates via `<?php get_header('blog); ?>`

In your new header file use the rel link you've got for custom favicon. That's it :)